# Android Network Data Transfer Analysis

Tags: android, ddms, data-transfer

I'm trying to analyze the network data transfer between a server and my WebView. Is there a way to export/access the raw data that is gathered in DDMS? I'd like to analyze the Network Statistics beyond the png of the graph and the table values provided. I'm imagining a simple csv file containing time|RX|TX.

If someone can suggest a method to extract this data via code that'd be fine too, though if an "export" method in DDMS exists I'd love to be exposed to it.

Comment: you can enable chrome debugging in Android Web View and inspect it as HTML pages itself.

Comment: yup root access. I'll play with chrome's dev tools and report back.